# How to use proguard with Hyperledger Iroha?

Tags: android, kotlin, blockchain, hyperledger-iroha

I I have problem on proguard with Hyperledger Iroha on android.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug{
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

- when I did: minifyEnabled true after building release apk: app-release.apk, the app crashed.
- when I did: minifyEnabled false after building release apk: app-release.apk, the app is okay.
- Result error is:

  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.domain.testava, PID: 20827
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
      at d.a.a.a.a.b.c.a(:69)
      at d.a.a.a.a.a.(:18)
      at b.a.a.a.a(:23)
      at com.domain.testava.MainActivity.onCreate(:14)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6675)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported hash algorithm
      at d.a.a.a.a.b.d.(:47)
      at d.a.a.a.a.b.b.(:18)
      at d.a.a.a.a.b.c.(:37)
      at d.a.a.a.a.b.c.a(:69) 
      at d.a.a.a.a.a.(:18) 
      at b.a.a.a.a(:23) 
      at com.domain.testava.MainActivity.onCreate(:14) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6675) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

[error screen on minifyEnabled true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IreBe.png)